# how to navigate to object detail page from lightning:card title

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller

I have a list of projects displayed using lightning:card. I would like the user to click on the title and then navigate to the record detail page. I referred to some posts online but couldn't make it work. Can anyone point out where i did wrong?

```
         <aura:Iteration items="{!v.lstProject}" var="item"> 


         <lightning:card   iconName="standard:scan_card" >
             <aura:set  attribute="title"  >
                        <a href=""  onClick="{!c.navigateToProject}">{!item.project.SFDC_Project_Name__c}</a>
             </aura:set>
```

---- controller.js code-----

```
    navigateToProject : function(component, event, helper) {
     var navEvent = $A.get('e.force:navigateToSObject');  

    var project = component.get("v.item");
    console.log('project event ' + project.id);

     navEvent.setParams({
         "recordId":  "a095B000006WLy5QAG", --- i hard-coded this for testing purpose but didn't work. also the above console.log was not displayed at all.
       "slideDevName": "detail"
   });
    navEvent.fire();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce documentation says that

> We recommend using lightning:navigation component with the standard__recordPage page type instead.

force:navigateToSObject is old way of navigation and creates unreadable url format. But with the introduction of lightning:isUrlAddressable interface and lightning:navigation library, we can have user readable URL formats and getting parameters from url in component (via state).

So please use:

.cmp file:

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

js:

```
navigateToProject : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("navService").navigate({
      "type": "standard__recordPage",
           "attributes": {
               "recordId": "a095B000006WLy5QAG",
               "objectApiName": "Project__c",
               "actionName": "view"
           }
    });
}
```

Refer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm for all pageReference types

Comment: Thank you. i used <a href="{!'/'+ item.project.Id}" >{!item.project.SFDC_Project_Name__c}</a> to make it work.